# How to Add User Role Label Next to Comments in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm newbie in wordpress, i want to display user role in comment like this tutorial --> https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-user-role-label-next-to-comments-in-wordpress/ but it not working? User role not showing..

the comments.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form.
 *
 * @package MDLWP
 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
 * return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="mdl-card__supporting-text comments mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card">

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h3 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( _nx( 'Satu komen &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s komen &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'mdlwp' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h3>

        <ol class="comment-list"> 
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'      => 'ol',
                    'short_ping' => true,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'mdlwp' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'mdlwp' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'mdlwp' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @Vel i added the code

Comment: @Vel Yes, it not displaying

Comment: Its working fine for me. check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwrns.jpg.

which theme you are using?

Did you enable the comments on admin panel?

Comment: I'm using MDLWP Theme --> http://mdlwp.com/ . Yes, i already enable the comments on admin panel.

Comment: can you share me the site url?

Comment: Sorry for late reply..this is my url site --> https://www.toonlah.com/komik/dango/ep-1/

Comment: How to post code here..

Comment: ok..already update..hope it help